# Problems connecting to an access database

Tags: .net, odbc

Im having problems connecting to an access database found in the following path: C:\tgs_webedit\pool\n_pool.mdb.

Im using odbc connection and my problem is in the following line:
OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection("DNS = C:\tgs_webedit\pool\n_pool.mdb");

Im getting the following error : System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to this:

```
OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ = C:\\tgs_webedit\\pool\\n_pool.mdb");
```

If you want to use a DSN, then don't provide the path to the mdb file (and put DSN in your conneciton string in stead of DNS).  If you are going to use a path, use the DBQ and escape the slashes.  Here is a good link that goes over all of this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.connectionstring.aspx

Comment: I used what u suggested and got more errors: Not a valid file name. and General Warning Unable to open registry key 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0x140c Thread 0x1368 DBC 0x4cfc64c Jet'

Comment: Are you positive that file exists?  There aren't any typos in your path?

Answer (score 1):

The syntactical problem:

Either use a @-string `OdbcConnection(@"DNS = C:\tgs_webedit\pool\n_pool.mdb");` or escape the backslashes `OdbcConnection("DNS = C:\\tgs_webedit\\pool\\n_pool.mdb");`

The functional problem:

An ODBC DSN connection should specify a DSN **name** defined in the ODBC datasources. The driver may 'do the right thing' - or not. To be on the save side, test getting your connection in the standard way*.

- standard way

Use "control panel" - "Administrative Tasks" - "Data Sources (ODBC)" to add a User or System DSN. Pick the Access driver, specify the Data Source Name and select/browse for your n_pool.mdb. You can then test the connection and perhaps set some options. Use the Data Source Name in your connection string. (Using Abe Miessler's way (dsn-less connection) may be faster to try out, but the Data Sources GUI makes it easier to hunt down problems)

Comment: how can i get it in a standard way? Any links that can help?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with x64, Microsoft JET4.0 only works with x86 (or maybe I am totaly wrong and this has nothing to to with JET and the non-porting problem to x64)